# Why isn't my for each loop working in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Right now I am just trying to detect when the person touches the screen but I keep getting an error saying: error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `:', expecting`)', `,',`;', `[', or`='. The rest of the code may not be right either, but I can't get the for each loop to work and I can't figure it out.

```
    for (var touch: Touch in Input.touches) {
        if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            Move(new Vector3(0, 0, 1));
    }
```

Comment: Learn about the basic syntax of the foreach loop.

Comment: I used what was on the unity website and I thought this would be accurate and I am pretty new

Comment: That's Javascript, not C#.

Comment: Yes using the unity examples be very careful you have the correct language selected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in C# you need to use the keyword foreach for enumerating over a list like that:

i.e.

```
foreach (var touch in Input.touches) {
        if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            Move(new Vector3(0, 0, 1));
    }
```

Edit:

> I used what was on the unity website and I thought this would be
>   accurate and I am pretty new

You can select C# or Javascript on Unity Reference website. If you select C#, you will get C# sample code. You got the code in your question because you selected Javascript .

[image]